# Delete Oracle table space/ data file and restart the database

Tags: oracle, unix, data-files

I accidentally deleted (manually) a data file from the server before deleting the tablespace from Oracle. So now I can't use my database. Is there any way to save the situation ?

```
conn / as sysdba
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2466250752 bytes
Fixed Size                  3713816 bytes
Variable Size             788530408 bytes
Database Buffers         1660944384 bytes
Redo Buffers               13062144 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> recover database until cancel
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01110: data file 7: '/u01/app/oracle/mytablespaces/erstedb1.dbf'
ORA-01122: database file 7 failed verification check
ORA-01110: data file 7: '/u01/app/oracle/mytablespaces/erstedb1.dbf'
ORA-01210: data file header is media corrupt
```

Comment: And you don't have a backup of your database or your file system?

Comment: Unfortunately no. the more important thing for me now is to be able to use the data base even if i'm going to lose data.

Comment: I mean if there any way to delete file '/u01/app/oracle/mytablespaces/erstedb1.dbf' ?

Comment: Try to create same empty file manually.(same name as deleted .dbf file and same location) Open database. Delete datafile using alter database drp datafile.

Comment: I tried to recreate all dbf files and the issue still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a backup, you will loose data. If you want to open the database in order to use the rest of the data, you can offline the data file:

```
shutdown immediate
startup nomount
alter database datafile '/u01/ORCL/file01.dbf' offline;
alter database open;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run on archivelog mode, reference this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nzbh7F3VrQQ. I faced similar issue and followed these steps in clip to fix then it worked

In my case, I did as following to recover deleted datafile:
-

- Shutdown immediate
- Startup mount
- alter database datafile 56 offline;
- alter database open;
- alter database create datafile 'F:\ORACLE\ORADATA\STAN1\SMSGW_INDEX01.DBF';
- recover datafile 56;

  - type AUTO
- alter database datafile 56 online;

After recover completed, you start from beginning again.